# update UILabel with current time continuosly when the app is in background

Tags: ios7, uilabel, xcode5, nstimer, background-process

When I try to update the `UILabel` with current time during the app in background,the label is not updated. It was working fine with xCode 4.6.2 but when xCode 5 iOS 7 it is not updating.

```
NSTimer *preventSleepTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(mmp_playPreventSleepSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I am calling "mmp_playPreventSleepSound" this method say after every 5 sec but it doesn't call this method and the app gets terminated after 5 min.

Please give me a solution so that I can update the `UILabel` text while in background and app should be running continuously?

Comment: Why do you need to update the Label if nos visible? Why not set it when app becomes active?

Comment: i need my app should run continuosly when the mpmovieplayer is pause. It gets terminated after 5 mins when the MPMoviePlayerControler is paused and the app going to background

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good idea. You should implement methods

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

and when application will enter the foreground you can update you label

If you want to play audio in background use AV Foundation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html

Comment: I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play Audio/Video files from the server. When i PAUSE the player and click on home button the app goes into background and after 5 mins the app gets terminated,I want to prevent it from termination. PANDORA app when PAUSE audio files and goes to background the app doesn't terminate. But my app gets terminate by the iOS. Is there any solution to prevent from termination?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use AV Foundation to achieve background playing of audio